# Android Compose - Align child views inside Box by parent view

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I have tried severals techniques including nested Box, Vertical/Horizontal alignment to the Child/Parent view without success, I'm trying to align the `Row` View in the top start Corner of the inner parent (Lottie view)

**Important**

the parent (column) need to be `fillMaxSize` and centered Vertically for other non-related elements

```
  Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally) {
            Header()
    
            Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart) {
    
                
               LottieView()
    
                Row(horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start, verticalAlignment = Alignment.Top) {
                    Button(onClick = {
    
                      .....
    
    
                    }) {
    
                        Text(text = "Open")
    
                    }
    
                }
            }
    
        }
```

Comment: In your Box you are using `Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.CenterStart)`. It is the reason of your issue.

Comment: Tried to remove it, the Row will appear at the top Corner of the parent (the column) and I want it in the top corner of the LottieView @GabrieleMariotti

Comment: Use a [Layout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/custom) or use for the Row the same alignment applied to the LottieView.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti My LottieView doesn't have any alignment, it's a default Modifier applied by the library, it's currently aligned in the center because of the Column alignments

Comment: The `LottieView` is inside a `Box`, it can't depend on the `Column` alignment. If you are using the [`LottieAnimation`](https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-android/blob/master/lottie-compose/src/main/java/com/airbnb/lottie/compose/LottieAnimation.kt) composable, you can use the `alignment` parameter (default value `Alignment.Center`).

Comment: Okay I noticed the LottieView is higher than expected with a transparent background, so I use  the Modifier ``Offset(x,y)`` @GabrieleMariotti. You got any better idea?

Comment: Can you provide the documentation of the LottieView?